# VHDL:clock divider

Tags: vhdl

i have 27MHz frequency at the input and want to get 400Hz, 100Hz and 1Hz frequencies at the output. but when i simulate it i dont get anything its just undefined, i dont have any idea what's wrong.

code

```
entity clk_div is
    port 
    (
        clk : in std_logic;
        clock_set : in std_logic;
        clk1_out : out std_logic;
        clk100_out : out std_logic;
        clk400_out : out std_logic

    );

end entity;


architecture rtl of clk_div is
signal q : std_logic_vector(24 downto 0);
begin
    process (clk)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            q <= q+1;
        end if;
    end process;
    clk1_out <= q(24);      --  1Hz freq
    clk400_out <= q(15);    --400Hz freq
    clk100_out <= q(17);    --100Hz freq


end rtl;
```

Comment: You can't derive exact frequencies by just using a bit from a counter. Your 100 Hz output runs at 102.99... Hz that's an error of 3% and maybe it's in the range of tollerance. But your 1Hz output runs at 0.80... Hz that's a fault of -20 %! You can reduce the error by using more bits or by using a cascaded synchronous frequency divider.

Comment: You should also include a reset signal which will zero everything out when high.  Then, start your simulation or on chip process by resetting the component before generating the new divided signal.  Including resets on all components is a good practice and will help you avoid situations such as this.  If all signals have a default reset state and you always start from reset, you won't be undefined (unless you do something really strange!).

Answer (score 2):

`q` is never initalised, so when you add one to it, the result is not defined.

You need something like:

```
signal q : std_logic_vector(24 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

Also, you are performing a mathematical operation on an std_logic_vector. This is not recommended; you should have a look at using the `numeric_std` package, and make your counter type `unsigned`.

Comment: Yeah, numeric_std is the way to go.